# How to add two functions to a new function in R

Tags: r

I met a problem adding two functions together to a new function in R. For example, fun_1<-function(w)...   fun_2<-function(w)...   now I need to get a function fun(w)=fun_1(w)+fun_2(w) how could I do it?

Comment: Please review [mcve].  `fun_1 <- function(w) ...` is *not* an example.

Comment: Do you just mean `fun <- function(w) fun_1(w)+fun_2(w) `? How is that different than the other functions you wrote?

Comment: This is a simplified problem. My problem is that when I am running a for loop in r for (i in 1:100). For each i, i have a different function fun_i(w). How could I add all this functions of w together to a new function?

Comment: Please describe your actual problem, not the simplified problem. Why are you creating functions in a for loop? There is likely a better way to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean this ?

```
fun_1 <- function(x){
  x ^ 2
}

fun_2 <- function(x){
  x + 1
}

fun_3 <- function(x){
  fun_1(x) + fun_2(x)
}

fun_3(1)
```

returns `3`

```
k <- NA
fun <- function(w){
  for (i in 1:100){
  k[i] <- (-i/100)^2 + exp(w)
  }
  sum(k)
}
fun(1)
```

returns `305.6632`

Comment: This is a simplified problem. My problem is that when I am running a for loop in r for (i in 1:100). For each i, i have a different function fun_i(w). How could I add all this functions of w together to a new function?

Comment: for(i in 1:100){fun<-functon(w){(-i/100)^2+exp(w)}} I would like to add all these functions in the for loop together to get a new function about w.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `get` with `envir = parent.frame()` and just use `paste` to specify the function name.

```
# define functions
for(i in 1:100) assign(paste0('fun',i), function(w) (-i/100)^2+exp(w) )

# sum them
sum.fun <- function(x){
  out <- 0
  for(i in 1:100){
    fun <- get(paste0('fun',i), envir = parent.frame())
    out <- out + fun(x)
  }
  out
}



sum.fun(2)
```